# Extract indices of cells meeting criteria from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame in pandas like this:

```
  a b c
A 1 2 3 
B 4 5 6
C 7 8 9
```

I want to extract the pairs of index name and column name whose cell has a value bigger than 6.

In other words, I want to obtain

```
[["B","c"], ["C","a"], ["C","b"], ["C","c"]]
```

Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html?highlight=stack#pandas.DataFrame.stack) to flatten the frame to a series, use boolean indexing to select the terms you want, and finally turn the resulting index into a list:

```
s = df.stack()
ii = s[s >= 6].index.tolist()
```

For example:

```
>>> s = df.stack()
>>> s
A  a    1
   b    2
   c    3
B  a    4
   b    5
   c    6
C  a    7
   b    8
   c    9
dtype: int64
>>> s[s >= 6]
B  c    6
C  a    7
   b    8
   c    9
dtype: int64
>>> s[s >= 6].index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B', u'C'], [u'a', u'b', u'c']],
           labels=[[1, 2, 2, 2], [2, 0, 1, 2]])
>>> s[s >= 6].index.tolist()
[('B', 'c'), ('C', 'a'), ('C', 'b'), ('C', 'c')]
```

Note that (1) I'm using `>= 6` because that matches your example, and (2) this is strictly a list of tuples not a list of lists like you asked for, but you can convert if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the NumPy route and use [`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) and [`np.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

Make an array of the row and column labels and use `np.argwhere` to return the integer indexes where the given condition holds. Use `np.choose` to retrieve the corresponding row and column index labels:

```
>>> xy = np.column_stack((df.index, df.columns))
>>> np.choose(np.argwhere(df >= 6), xy)
array([['B', 'c'],
       ['C', 'a'],
       ['C', 'b'],
       ['C', 'c']], dtype=object)
```

This returns an array: you can use `tolist()` to get back Python lists:

```
>>> np.choose(np.argwhere(df >= 6), xy).tolist()
[['B', 'c'], ['C', 'a'], ['C', 'b'], ['C', 'c']]
```